# How can I persist state of slideToggle() in my case?

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

I want javascript function slideToggle() to persist it's state. For now, everytime i refresh the page, it looses the information. i know it can be done using cookies or localstorage but i have failed to do so..

I would really be thankful if someone could show me how to implement a solution in my code;

```
//toggle hide/show shout box
$(".close_btnn").click(function (e) {   
    //get CSS display state of .toggle_chat element
            var toggleState = $('.toggle_chat').css('display');
    //toggle show/hide chat box
    $('.toggle_chat').slideToggle();

    //use toggleState var to change close/open icon image
    if(toggleState == 'block')
    {
        $(".header div").attr('class', 'open_btnn');
    }else{
        $(".header div").attr('class', 'close_btnn');

    }


});
```

This is the HTML/PHP of the page with the shoutbox;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.shout_box {
background: #000000;
width: 260px;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 10px;
z-index:9;
}
.shout_box .header .close_btn {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px;
float: right;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
.shout_box .header .close_btn:hover {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -16px;
}

.shout_box .header .open_btn {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -32px;
float: right;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
.shout_box .header .open_btn:hover {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -48px;
}
.shout_box .header{
padding: 5px 3px 5px 5px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color:#fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 39, 121, .76);
border-bottom:none;
cursor: pointer;
}
.shout_box .header:hover{
background-color: #000000;
}
.shout_box .message_box {
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 200px;
overflow:auto;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.shout_msg{
margin-bottom: 10px;
display: block;
border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
color:#7C7C7C;
}
.message_box:last-child {
border-bottom:none;
}
time{
    font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
float:right;
color: #D5D5D5;
}
.shout_msg .username{
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.user_info input {
width: 98%;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-top: none;
padding: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
.shout_msg .username{
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="shoutbox/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// load messages every 1000 milliseconds from server.
load_data = {'fetch':1};
//window.setInterval(function(){
 $.post('shoutbox/shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {
    $('.message_box').html(data);
    var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
 });
//}, 1000);

//method to trigger when user hits enter key
$("#shout_message").keypress(function(evt) {
    if(evt.which == 13) {
            var iusername = "java";
            var imessage = $('#shout_message').val();
            post_data = {'username':iusername, 'message':imessage};

            //send data to "shout.php" using jQuery $.post()
            $.post('shoutbox/shout.php', post_data, function(data) {

                //append data into messagebox with jQuery fade effect!
                $(data).hide().appendTo('.message_box').fadeIn();

                //keep scrolled to bottom of chat!
                var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
                $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);

                //reset value of message box
                $('#shout_message').val('');

            }).fail(function(err) { 

            //alert HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        }
});

//toggle hide/show shout box
$(".close_btn").click(function (e) {
    //get CSS display state of .toggle_chat element
    var toggleState = $('.toggle_chat').css('display');

    //toggle show/hide chat box
    $('.toggle_chat').slideToggle();

    //use toggleState var to change close/open icon image
    if(toggleState == 'block')
    {
        $(".header div").attr('class', 'open_btn');
    }else{
        $(".header div").attr('class', 'close_btn');
    }


});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="shout_box">
<div class="header">Shout Box <div class="close_btn">&nbsp;</div></div>
  <div class="toggle_chat">
  <div class="message_box">
    </div>
    <div class="user_info">

   <input name="shout_message" id="shout_message" type="text" placeholder="Type Message Hit Enter" maxlength="100" /> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what did you meant by persisting state? do you want to keep the chat box open even after browser refresh? Could you provide html of your javascript? There must be some condition that needs to be fulfilled to keep the state persisted, what is it in your project?

Comment: i mean that at the moment whenever i refresh the page, at default the chat box is always open. i would like that if a user closes it, it stays closed for whenever the user opens the site.. (i edited the previous post to show you the full html of the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using `localstorage`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var $shoutBox = $('#shout-box');
var isShoutBoxClosed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoutBoxClosed'));
if(isShoutBoxClosed){
 $shoutBox.hide();
} 
//toggle hide/show shout box
$(".close_btn").click(function (e) {
 //save users preference on localstoage
 localStorage.setItem('shoutBoxClosed', true);
    //toggle show/hide chat box
  $shoutBox.slideToggle();

});
 
});
```

```css
.shout_box {
background: #000000;
width: 260px;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 10px;
z-index:9;
}
.shout_box .header .close_btn {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px;
float: right;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
.shout_box .header .close_btn:hover {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -16px;
}

.shout_box .header .open_btn {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -32px;
float: right;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
.shout_box .header .open_btn:hover {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -48px;
}
.shout_box .header{
padding: 5px 3px 5px 5px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color:#fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 39, 121, .76);
border-bottom:none;
cursor: pointer;
}
.shout_box .header:hover{
background-color: #000000;
}
.shout_box .message_box {
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 200px;
overflow:auto;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.shout_msg{
margin-bottom: 10px;
display: block;
border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
color:#7C7C7C;
}
.message_box:last-child {
border-bottom:none;
}
time{
    font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
float:right;
color: #D5D5D5;
}
.shout_msg .username{
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.user_info input {
width: 98%;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-top: none;
padding: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
.shout_msg .username{
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="shout-box" class="shout_box">
<div class="header">Shout Box <div class="close_btn">X</div></div>
  <div class="toggle_chat">
  <div class="message_box">
    </div>
    <div class="user_info">

   <input name="shout_message" id="shout_message" type="text" placeholder="Type Message Hit Enter" maxlength="100" /> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsbin of the above snippet https://jsbin.com/hewataz/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out you can use a cookie to save the user preference. You can read more about [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

When the user clicks the button to toggle the chat you will set the cookie to that preference. Then when the page loads you will read the cookie and set the css on the chat box. Here is an example and a working fiddle

https://fiddle.jshell.net/75nrozxd/1

```
<div class="shout_box">
  <div class="header">Shout Box
    <div class="close_btn">Toggle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle_chat">
    <div class="message_box">
    </div>
    <div class="user_info">
      <input name="shout_message" id="shout_message" type="text" placeholder="Type Message Hit Enter" maxlength="100" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)chatCSS\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
console.log("Cookie Value is: " + cookieValue)
$('.toggle_chat').css("display", cookieValue);

//toggle hide/show shout box
$(".close_btn").click(function(e) {
  //get CSS display state of .toggle_chat element
  //toggle show/hide chat box
  $('.toggle_chat').slideToggle(function() {
    var toggleState = $('.toggle_chat').css('display');
    document.cookie = "chatCSS=" + toggleState;
    //use toggleState var to change close/open icon image
    if (toggleState == 'block') {
      $(".header div").attr('class', 'open_btn');
    } else {
      $(".header div").attr('class', 'close_btn');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```